# Getting similar rows from Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello friends I am having following table structure of quote Table

[image]

I want to access all similar quotes (which have same author_id and category_id) for a particular _id(quoteId)

Earlier

Similar quotes means all columns of all those rows of this table of same category_id **and** same author_id. Two quotes can be considered as similar if their authors are same and category are same.

so I was using following query for this

```
 SELECT `related_quote`.* FROM
     `quote` AS `main_quote` LEFT JOIN 
    `quote` AS `related_quote`
     USING(`author_id`, `category_id`)
    WHERE `main_quote`.`_id` = QUOTE_ID
```

But now for some other requirement the definition of similar quotes changed slightly

Similar quotes means all columns of all those rows of this table of same category_id **or** same author_id. Two quotes can be considered as similar if their authors are same and category are same.

Please help me to create the query for **OR** condition 
thanks in adv

Comment: should i replace using clause with ON

Comment: yes that's what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT related_quote.*
FROM quote AS main_quote
  LEFT JOIN quote AS related_quote
    ON (related_quote.author_id = main_quote.author_id OR
        related_quote.category_id = main_quote.category_id)
WHERE main_quote._id = main_quote._ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
SELECT
  t1.column1,
  t1.column2,
  t2.column1,
  t2.column2,
  t3.column1,
  t3.column2
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t2.ForeignKey = t1.primaryKey)
  LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t3.foreignKey = t2.PrimaryKey)
WHERE t1.columnName = 'somevalue';
```